# Sorting linked list in descending order

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, text-files

I have a function that inserts 1000 lines into a linked list, each line gets inserted at end.  But I need modify it so it will organize the linked list in descending order based on a number in the very front of the line. But I am really having trouble figuring out how to do that... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
void Term :: InsertAtEnd(string file, int size)
{
    struct node *temp, *temp_2;
    temp_2 = start;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        temp_2 = temp_2 -> next;
    }
    temp = new(node);
    temp -> text = file;
    if (temp_2 -> next == NULL)
    {
        temp_2 -> next = temp;
        temp -> next = NULL;
        temp -> prev = temp_2;      
    }
    else
    {
        temp -> next = temp_2 -> next;
        temp -> next -> prev = temp;
        temp_2 -> next = temp;
        temp -> prev = temp_2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use `std::vector` or `std::list` and `std::sort` instead ?

Comment: You need to sort your list, but instead of usual comparison used in sorting algorithms (like "less" or "greater") you would use your own predicate that reads numbers in strings and compares them. For well-written sorting functions (like [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)) you may pass such a predicate as an argument.

Comment: You have two problems: 1) extract the number at the beginning of a string, and 2) sort the elements of the list. Which one are you having trouble with?

Comment: Noting that the code you have presented is only concerned with inserting nodes, and you have asked about how to sort your linked list, what have you actually tried?